# Express.js collection.find() return Object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

I am wanted to display every documents stored in my mongodb. I tried following code which simply get collection.find() and display through res.send()

```
router.get('/index', function(req,res){
var db = req.db
var collection = db.get('usercollection')

var display = util.inspect(collection.find()));
res.send(display);
});
```

I expected it to display the actual document stored in mongodb. But instead, it displayed this object format:

```
{cold:{manager:{driver:[Object], helper:[Object], collection:[Object].....
```

Is there any other steps needed to display raw mongodb document?

Comment: thats a MEAN stack bro

Answer (score 1):

If the library you are using is the [official 10gen library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb), then you can't simply output `collection.find()` without unwinding it. The easiest way to do that for smaller datasets is

```
collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
      // do something error-y
  } else {
      res.send( results );
  }
});
```

If you post more of your code, and tag your question with the libraries you are using, you'll be able to get more targeted help. If the library you are using returns a [promise](https://www.promisejs.org/), this is probably how you'd unwind it:

```
collection.find().then(function(results){
    res.send(results);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: I believe, you can use `res.send` only once per request.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I tried after I explored StackOverflow. I have an error says "Object #<Promise> has no method 'toArray'. Seems toArray is not default method?

Comment: i've updated my answer to include my best guess on how you'd handle the `Promise` return object.

Comment: @thefourtheye, `res.end()` is the function you can only use once. `res.send` can be used as many times as you like. @Taewan should note that the response needs to be explicitly closed. Many people just use `res.end( response_object )` once to send and close in one go, relieving you of having to remember close the connection